# CRM Reports: Grouping by a related Entity

Tags: t-sql, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

There is an N<>N relationship between Contacts and Complaints.

My report currently looks like this:

```
      Status 1    Status 2    Status 3    Status 4
         3           4           32          34
```

With the following query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(case WHEN status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Status1,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Status2,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Status3,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Status4,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 5 then 1 else 0 end) Status5
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Contact]
```

This is listing the number of contacts in each status.  I'm now trying to GROUP BY a field in a related entity in CRM - complaints.

```
                                         Status 1    Status 2    Status 3    Status 4
Contact.Complaints.CreatedBy[1]             3           4           32          34
Contact.Complaints.CreatedBy[2]             3           4           32          34
Contact.Complaints.CreatedBy[3]             3           4           32          34
Contact.Complaints.CreatedBy[4]             3           4           32          34
```

I'm not sure where to get started in my GROUP BY statement - any pointers would be awesome.  I feel like I have to have another FROM statement pointing to the NN relationship, or at least Complaints.

Comment: If you're just starting to learn SQL, I'd like to recommend the learning site [www.sql-ex.ru](http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php). Yeah, it's a Russian site, but I haven't found any better site for learning SQL. At some point, they get to groupings and joins, which should be helpful to you in this question.

Comment: You should be using the Filtered views, e.g. FilteredContact, then the security model of CRM it still applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as easy as adding a JOIN to Complaints (thru the N:N) table.  I completely agree with James, just make sure you execute the report as a CRM user, otherwise Filtered views return 0 rows.

```
SELECT
MyComplaintType,
...existing Sum(Case) stuff

FROM
FilteredContacts c
JOIN
Filterednew_Contacts_new_Complaint_new_complaints r1 (whatever your N:N is)
  ON c.contactId = r1.contactId
JOIN
Filterednew_Complaint comp
  ON r1.new_complaintId = comp.new_complaintId
GROUP BY
MyComplaintType
```